# Windows 8.1: Exporting image from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, windows-8, export, windows-8.1

I've been working or sort of a paint program for Windows 8 in JavaScript, But I've stumbled upon a problem. I have no idea how to export a image from a canvas. I'm kind of familiar with the FileSavePicker but I need help.

I found this but I don't know how to create a "encoding" variable: [Saving a Canvas as an image in Windows 8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cf8c17dc-68d4-4777-951f-bb7f0665bd06/saving-a-canvas-as-an-image-in-windows-8)

If there's a simpler way or if someone could explain it that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately to solve several issues using Html to make a Windows 8 app, I switched to C# and Xaml.

I used to like Html and JavaScript because it was familiar, but after I learned more about Xaml and C# I started to like it better. For example, instead of using `<div>` for almost every section of interface, you can use a, `<Grid>`, `<Border>`,`<StackPanel>`, and more. But for this particular problem I solved it pretty quickly.

```
public async void Preview_Update()
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);
    image.Source = bitmap;
}
```

And for the FileSavePicker, it's pretty simple: [FileSavePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use canvas.toDataURL() to create an image from your canvas.

Then you can open that image in a new window like this:

```
    var win=window.open();
    win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
```

Your user can do the usual right-click-save in that new window.

Here's working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle="gold";
    ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.rect(50,50,100,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    var win=window.open();
    win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get the chance.

Comment: Ok. I got the image file from the canvas. But is there a way to use the fileSavePicker to let the user save the image?

Comment: You can try using fileSavePicker directly, but you may run into cross-domain security issues depending on the source of your canvas content.  Here's a link using fileSavePicker:  http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9781449321222/pickers/id332473

Comment: I don't really understand how to use this. Could you give me an example? Maybe there's a way to convert it to bites and save it, is that a possibility?